# Kibana - Can I combine values from different rows into one based on aggregations?

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-5

Actual:

[image: Actual Result]

Expected:

[image: Expected Result]

I want to display it in a data table vis.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations available under Elastic search are Metric and Matrix.

Metric aggregations computes metrics over a set of documents

Matrix aggregations operates on multiple fields to compute the resultant value. But this is not yet available to do search under Kibana.

Best idea is to post this query under Community group of elastic search to get them knowing about this or better picture can be provided by them.